# Writing scraped data in rows with python

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a basic bs4 web scraper, There are no issues in getting my scrape data, but when I try to write it to a .csv file, I got some problems. I am unable to write my data to more than one column. In [the tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XQgXKtPSzUI) I kinda follow, he can separate rows with "," easily but when I open my CSV with excel, neither in the header nor in data there is a separation, what am I missing?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url="myurl"

page=requests.get(url)

soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')

items=soup.find_all('a', class_='listing-card')

filename = 'data.csv'
f = open(filename, "w")
header = "name, price\n"
f.write(header)

for item in items:
    title = item.find('span', class_='title').text
    price = item.find('span', class_='price').text
    f.write(title.replace(",","|") + ',' + price + "\n")

f.close()
```

Comment: What does `data.csv` look like when you open the file in a text editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another method.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc, utils, req
url = "myurl"
html = req.get(url)

rows = []
rows.append(['name', 'price'])  # Add header

doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
items = doc.getElements('a', attr='class', value='listing-card') # Get all nodes a according to the class
for item in items:
    title = item.getElement('span', value='title').text
    price = item.getElement('span', value='price').text
    rows.append([title, price])

utils.save2csv('data.csv', rows) # Save to CSV file
```

Here are more examples: https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples

Answer (score 1):

I have found that the easiest way to get your data into a CSV file is to put the data into a pandas DataFrame then use the to_csv method to write the file.

Using your example the code would be as follows:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url="myurl"

page=requests.get(url)

soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')

items=soup.find_all('a', class_='listing-card')

filename = 'data.csv'
f = open(filename, "w")
header = "name, price\n"
f.write(header)

#
# Create an empty list to store entries
mylist = []
for item in items:
    title = item.find('span', class_='title').text
    price = item.find('span', class_='price').text
    #
    # Create the dictionary item to be appended to the list
    entry = {'name' : title, 'price' : price}
    mylist.append(entry)
    
myDataframe =  pd.DataFrame(mylist) 
myDataframe.to_csv('CSV_file.csv')
```